# Update IProgressMonitor in IStatusLineManager after each worked()

Tags: java, eclipse, progress-bar, jface

I am trying to use a IProgressMonitor, but when I run my code, I do not see anything happen. If I eliminate pm.done(); I can see the progress monitor filling up and then staying there. Is there a way I can refresh the UI after each pm.worked() call, even if I have to pause my current thread.

```
public void someMethod(CutomerInfo cInfo) {

    IStatusLineManager lm = getViewSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager();
    IProgressMonitor pm = lm.getProgressMonitor();
    pm.beginTask("Doing some work",  100);

    populateCustomerInfo();
    pm.worked(25);

    someOtherFunction();
    pm.worked(25);

    morefunctions();
    pm.worked(25);

    this.someValue = someClass.yetAnotherFunction(this.cInfo, this);
    pm.worked(25);

    pm.done();
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I added Job to my function, and now looks like the code below. I know the job is running, but i do not see the progress bar. Is there a way to pass the progress monitor I have defined as *pm*?

```
public void someMethod(CutomerInfo cInfo) {

    Job job = new Job("Test Job") {

  IStatusLineManager lm = getViewSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager();
  IProgressMonitor pm = lm.getProgressMonitor();

  @Override
  protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            // Set total number of work units
            monitor.beginTask("start task", 100);

    try {
      System.out.println("\nHello World (from a background job)\n");

      monitor.subTask("doing a");
      populateCustomerInfo();
      monitor.worked(25);

      monitor.subTask("doing b");
      someOtherFunction();
      monitor.worked(25);

      monitor.subTask("doing c");
      morefunctions();
      monitor.worked(25);

      monitor.subTask("doing d");
      yetAnotherFunction();
      monitor.worked(25);

      monitor.done();
    }catch (InterruptedException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };

    job.schedule();
}
```

Comment: The JavaDoc for `IStatusLineManager.getProgressManager` says: Note that the returned progress monitor may only be accessed from the UI thread. So I don't think your code is actually running in an non-UI thread.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question.

Comment: No, you can't change the progress monitor that is used. If you call `setUser(true)` on the Job before you schedule it the progress will be displayed in a pop dialog (but only if the Job runs for more than about 2 seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long running tasks must be run in a background thread. Running them in the UI thread will stop the UI from updating.

In this case you probably want to use an Eclipse `Job`. The main `run` method of a Job is given a progress monitor which will be displayed in the status line.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: I added a job, but I do not see the progress monitor at all. Please see edit 1. Thanks.

Comment: Job progress is normally displayed in the progress area at the bottom right of the main Eclipse window.